# How do you get 'overheal' in Deus Ex?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

As I got into the Hive through the women's bathroom, I noticed that my health was not the usual 100, but 125. I did check a few doors and toilets on my way through, but doing so after I noticed the change in health didn't get me another bump upwards. I have thus no idea about what happened there.

Why is my health suddenly 125? Excluding hypostims and other health items (I don't recall using any), what does bump your health beyond 100?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've got exactly 125 health, it seems very likely to me that you inadvertently popped some [Painkillers](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Painkillers) - they give you 25 health, if you're already at 100, or up to 50 if you're below 100.

Besides Painkillers and the Hypostim, certain types of alcohol (beer, wine, vodka, and certain mixed drinks you can order in bars) can also increase your health above 100, but it tends to be in increments of 10 health, which seems like it would make reaching exactly 125 difficult.

Comment: I guess accidentally taking painkillers is more like it.

Comment: Great, just what we need, our mods are popping pills

Comment: @BenBrocka, if there's one thing I've learned from video games, it's that if I get hurt, I should immediately down the nearest bottle of whatever pills I can find.  It's a strategy that has worked for me so far.  WHAT COULD POSSIBLY GO WRONG???

Comment: @Ben PILLS HERE!